# Create a specific Mindmap diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Where can I find examples of Mindmap diagrams like that of the attached figure? Thanks a lot. No need for complete solution just some guidelines.

[image]

found [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups?p_auth=54LxAnA8&p_p_id=19&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=6&_19_struts_action=%2Fmessage_boards%2Fget_message_attachment&_19_messageId=1017231&_19_attachment=NewFeaturesInWolfram11.pdf). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the comment. Actually I found (almost) what I want here! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319284/mind-map-type-that-i-didnt-find-out

Comment: Nice. I hadn't seen this.